# Growth Rate Per Row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am working on a dataset for a welfare wage subsidy program, where wages per worker are structured as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(wage_1990 = c(13451.67, 45000, 10301.67, NA, NA, 
8726.67, 11952.5, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, 
NA, 9881.67, 5483.33, 12868.33, 9321.67), wage_1991 = c(13451.67, 
45000, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8750, 11952.5, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 
10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 5483.33, 12868.33, 9321.67
), wage_1992 = c(13451.67, 49500, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8750, 11952.5, 
NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, NA, 
12868.33, 9321.67), wage_1993 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8750, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 
NA, NA, 9321.67), wage_1994 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8948.33, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 
NA, NA, 9321.67), wage_1995 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8948.33, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 
NA, NA, 9321.67), wage_1996 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8948.33, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7291.67, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 
9881.67, NA, NA, 9321.67)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I want to do the following:
1-Create a variable showing the annual growth rate of wage for each worker or lack of thereof.

The practical issue that I am facing is that each observation is in one row and while the first worker joined the program in 1990, others might have joined in say 1993 or 1992. Therefore, is there a way to apply the growth rate for each worker depending on the specific years they worked, rather than applying a general growth formula for all observations?

```
My expected output for each row would be having a new column

      average wage growth rate
1-         15%
2-         9%
3-         12%
```

Comment: pls kindly use `dput` instead of `str`

Comment: Thanks, does that help?

Comment: the three columns in your data frame have different lengths. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not use your data because your data variables have different lengths.  Therefore, I took your basic data and created two variables of the same length.  For the sake of brevity and to better explain this answer, I also reduced the number of variables down to the two most important items: (length of subsidy & wage 1990).  Finally, I removed your NA's and replaced them with the value, 0.

First step: created a data.frame with the two vectors of equal length
Second step: used functions from the dplyr package to organize the data (filter, mutate, 
             arrange)
Third step: used a plot to display data in order to reveal any structure in the data. The data I used is different, but this data did reveal some structure in the plot.

This sequence of code successfully created one method for producing the output you are searching for.  To further examine your data, you will need to include more variables into the df and perform further analysis using the various dplyr functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
sub <- c(110, 69, 370, 21, 77, 392, 355, 21, 27, 245, 21, 42)                   
wage <- c(13451.67, 45000.00, 10301.67, 0, 0, 8726.67, 11952.50, 0, 15700, 5100, 0, 500)

df <- data.frame(sub, wage)     # equal sized data vectors
df

c <- df %>% filter(df$wage > 0) %>% mutate(valu = wage / sub)   # mutate to shrink the y axis 
c                                    # to print the df

c2 <- c %>% arrange(desc(valu))                 # sort 
c2                                              # print df

ggplot(c2, aes(sub, valu))+                      # plot df
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helps! 
I have fixed some of the errors in my earlier post, hope it helps to reproduce the data.

Comment: Glad to assist and steer you in the right direction.